# How to "Freeze" some lines from editing at monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, monaco-editor

I want to load JavaScript file contents to the editor but "freeze" some lines. Best way to do that?

Let's say there are 100 lines of code.

I want the user to be able to edit anything between line 10-90th but don't allow to edit between 0-10th or 90-100th.

Doing that inside create-react-app application. Looking for way w/o ejecting the react scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution. While I'm working with `create-react-app` application I used this:

https://github.com/SurenAt93/monaco-react#controlled-editor

But the idea is the same no matter the environment.

The controlled editor allows listening `onChange` event and return new code. So on this handler, I'm checking if the required range is not changed and if it is, I don't allow that by returning unchanged code and showing nice notification to the user which is totally unrelated to this question.